# how to get class from which a method has been defined in ruby?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

Having the snippet below:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    puts self.class
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def bark
    puts self.class
  end
end

class Fizz < Bar
end

Fizz.new.bark
```

This snippet will output two times `Fizz` ([live example](https://repl.it/repls/PrimaryStarkEmbed)). I would like to find something to replace `self.class` which allows this program to output `Foo` (from initialize) and then `Bar` (from bark).

My current solution is to hardcode function name, but I'd like something more dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works. (*There's probably a better way, though.*)

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    puts method(__callee__).owner
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def bark
    puts method(__callee__).owner
  end
end

class Fizz < Bar
end

Fizz.new.bark
# >> Foo
# >> Bar
```

Comment: Prefer `__callee__` over `__method__` if you want it to work with aliases.

Comment: @mudasobwa, this really depends on which behavior you want. Sergio, knowing that I need this only in my initialize method would help getting something simpler?

Comment: I believe if in`Bar` you have `alias_method :bark, :initialize` you want `bark` to be reported as belonging to `Bar`.

Comment: @UlysseBN "something simpler" - this is not too complex/difficult as it is, no? :)

Comment: @UlysseBN _"I need this only in my initialize method"_ – may I ask why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: That would be another question I think: I want to know if initialize has been called directly, or using `super`. That is why I'm using class name to compare with `self.class`

Comment: @UlysseBN: <pedant mode on>`initialize` is never called directly by you. `new` calls it. It's a private method.</pedant mode off>

Comment: Well, the question is then *Has it been called by `new` or by `super`?*

Comment: @UlysseBN _"I want to know if initialize has been called directly, or using super"_ – may I ask why? (going to ask this 5 times)

Comment: @Stefan For abstraction purpose, I don't wan't to allow `intialize` to be called (by `new`). But It still has some logic in it for when it is called with `super`.

Comment: @UlysseBN: if you want to prevent creation of instances of some class, why not simply make its `new` private? (and open it back in the descendants)

Comment: @UlysseBN like a [`Singleton`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev by using `undef_method :new` for instance?

Comment: @Stefan didn't get your point there. I don't think I need (nor want) usage of Singleton here

Comment: @UlysseBN `Singleton` makes `new` private, thus preventing it from being called. I thought that maybe this is what you want. You didn't really explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Stefan, you're totally right. I think I have sufficient information now. Maybe I'll open another question self-answered to clarify this. I'm not sure this would be helpful though

Comment: @SergioTulentsev <pedant mode on> want a bet on me making direct `initialize` call ruining your “never called” proposition?</pedant mode off>

Comment: @mudasobwa: your pedantry is stronger, I concede :)